# How to draw lines in screenspace like grids in a perspective world?

Tags: geometry-shader

In my Geometry shader this is what my line shader looks like

```
PSInput output = (PSInput) 0;

// Bring A and B in window space
float2 AWidth = projToWindow(input[0]);
float2 Bwidth = projToWindow(input[1]);

float2 lineStrip = Bwidth.xy - AWidth.xy;
float2 normal = normalize(float2(-lineStrip.y, lineStrip.x));
float2 width = vObjectParams.x * normal;

// Compute the corners of the ribbon in window space
float2 Top1 = (AWidth + width);
float2 Top2 = (AWidth - width);
float2 Bottom1 = (Bwidth + width);
float2 Bottom2 = (Bwidth - width);

float Z  = input[0].z;
float Z1 = input[1].z;

//Bring the computed x and y back to world space
output.p = windowToProjection(Top1, Z, input[0].w);
outStream.Append(output);

output.p = windowToProjection(Top2, Z, input[0].w);
outStream.Append(output);

output.p = windowToProjection(Bottom1, Z1, input[1].w);
outStream.Append(output);

output.p = windowToProjection(Bottom2, Z1, input[1].w);
outStream.Append(output);

outStream.RestartStrip();
```

Basically, I bring the vector into the screen space first then add the required width then push it back to the world space.

Everything works fine when I am zoomed out but perspective geometry comes into play when I am zoomed in. That is, my line width increases as I zoom in closer